# Block number with BlockedNumberContract

Tags: java, android

According to Android Documentation there is a function called [BlockedNumberContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BlockedNumberContract.html) that gives ability to block specific phone number and add it to Blocked Numbers on user smartphone. There is an example on google site and it shows something like this:

```
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NUMBER, "1234567889");

    Uri uri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
```

I tried to use that on my app when user click a button specific number will be on block list. But When I click a button app stops and I got an error:

> Could not execute method for android:onClick

Does anybody have idea for this? Is there a place where I should put Uri to add number to Blocked Numbers?

**Permissions user**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

**EDIT: FULL ERROR**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: esticrm.pl.esticall, PID: 15235
>                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Caller must be system, default dialer or default SMS app
>                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
>                                                                            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                                                                            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                                                                            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
>                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1539)
>                                                                            at esticrm.pl.esticall.ListDetailsActivity.blockContact(ListDetailsActivity.java:45)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Please show the logcat of the error.

Comment: I've just updated post.

Comment: share your onclick code as well

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Caller must be system, default dialer or default SMS app 

It is giving security Exception check for permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the system, the default SMS application, and the default phone app (See getDefaultDialerPackage()), and carrier apps (See CarrierService) can read, and write to the blockednumber provider. However, canCurrentUserBlockNumbers(Context) can be accessed by any application.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BlockedNumberContract.html
follow the link

Answer (score 0):

A little bit later in the stack trace is this:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Caller must be system, default dialer or default SMS app

Comment: reason:
Permissions
Only the system, the default SMS application, and the default phone app (See getDefaultDialerPackage()), and carrier apps (See CarrierService) can read, and write to the blockednumber provider. However, canCurrentUserBlockNumbers(Context) can be accessed by any application.